# Remove Old Drive Without Break The OS Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have 2 Drives in my PC. Both of them have OS in them. Let say my primary OS in Drive 1 and secondary OS is in Drive 2.

I want to remove Drive 2, but when I remove it Drive 1 won't boot "No bootable devices are found". I already set the booting setting to drive 1 in BIOS. But seems some of boot files in Drive 2.

Is it possible to move just the boot files so my Drive 2 can be removed?

Comment: If I understand it correctly your Boot manager was installed on Drive 2. Hence why it doesn't boot from Drive 1 when Drive 2 is missing. The easiest way would be to reinstall the system on Drive 1 without Drive 2 being connected. This way you would garantie that it will install a boot manager on Drive 1. Another way would be to get a Linux Live CD and during testing you will have to install the the Grub2. Here a link with more. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: First part of the comment above is correct, it describes what's happening and what you need to understand. The second part not so much unless the OSes in question are Linux.